# Como colocar a linha de regressão em um gráfico?

Tags: r, regressão, plot, lm, ggplot2

Suponha um modelo de regressão linear como o seguinte:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100) + 2*x +10
modelo <- lm(y~x)
```

Se eu plotar y contra x, como faço para incluir a linha de regressão no gráfico?

```
plot(y~x)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Outra alternativa é utilizar o pacote [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/):

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100) + 2*x +10

require(ggplot2)
dados <- data.frame(x=x, y=y) # O ggplot2 exige que os dados estejam em um data.frame


p <- ggplot(dados, aes(x=x, y=y)) + # Informa os dados a serem utilizadps
    geom_point() # Informa que eu quero um gráfico de dispersão.
p
```

[image: Gráfico 1]

```
p1 <- p + geom_smooth(method=lm) # Acrescenta a linha de tendência e o intervalo de confiança de predição
p1
```

[image: Gráfico 2]

```
p2 <- p + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE) # Acrescenta a linha de tendência, sem o intervalo de predição
p2
```

[image: Gráfico 3]

Comment: o método tem que estar entre aspas. `geom_smooth(method="lm")`

Comment: Certeza? Aqui funciona sem as aspas.

Comment: Sim, certeza. Pode ser problemas com as versões. 
R Under development (unstable) (2014-02-06 r64930)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1.99

são as partes que eu achei relevantes de sessionInfo(). Vou conferir se pode ser um erro de instalação da minha parte.

Comment: Aqui: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25); Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit); ggplot2_0.9.3.1

Answer (score 8):

Você pode usar a função `abline` junto com `coef` para extrair os coeficientes do modelo e plotar a linha:

```
plot(y~x)
abline(coef(modelo))
```

[image: linha de regressão]

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra maneira é usar a função `curve`.

```
curve(coef(modelo)[1]+coef(modelo)[2]*x,add=TRUE,col = "blue",lwd=2)
```

Uma vantagem dessa função é que ela também serve caso o modelo envolva componentes não lineares. Como no caso abaixo:

```
n=1000
x1 = rnorm(n)
y = 5 +  4*x1 + 2*x1^2 + rnorm(n)
modelo <- lm( y ~ x1 + I(x1^2) )
plot(y~x1)
curve(coef(modelo)[1]+coef(modelo)[2]*x+coef(modelo)[3]*x^2,add=TRUE,col = "blue",lwd=2)
```

[image: Modelo não linear]

Answer (score 2):

É possível também trabalhar com gráfico interativo, caso necessário. Para tal, fica a dica do pacote `highcharter`.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100) + 2*x +10
dados <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

library(highcharter)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

highcharter::hchart(
  dados,   # data frame
  "point", # estilo do plot
  highcharter::hcaes(
    x = x, # columa de dados para eixo x
    y = y # columa de dados para eixo y
    ),
  regression = TRUE) %>% 
  highcharter::hc_colors("#d35400") %>% 
  highcharter::hc_add_dependency("plugins/highcharts-regression.js")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]