# Como colocar a equação da regressão em um gráfico?

Tags: r, regressão, plot, lm, ggplot2

[Em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6267/como-colocar-a-linha-de-regressao-em-um-grafico) viu-se como colocar  a linha de regressão em um gráfico. Mas, como colocar a equação da regressão no gráfico? Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segue uma possível solução, usando `geom_text`:

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100) + 2*x +10
modelo <- lm(y~x)
coeficientes <- modelo$coefficients
texto <- sprintf('y = %.2f + %.2fx, r² = %.2f', coeficientes[1], coeficientes[2], summary(modelo)$r.squared)

require(ggplot2)
dados <- data.frame(x=x, y=y) # O ggplot2 exige que os dados estejam em um data.frame

p <- ggplot(dados, aes(x=x, y=y)) + # Informa os dados a serem utilizadps
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(aes(x=min(x), y=max(y), label=texto), hjust=0, vjust=1)
p
```

[image: Gráfico obtido]
O `hjust=0` serve para informar que o x indicado é o do limite esquerdo do texto (padrão é o centro, .5) e `vjust=1` serve para informar que o y indicado é o limite superior do texto (mesmo padrao do hjust).

Answer (score 1):

Também é possível automatizar esses *output* com a função `stat_poly_eq` do pacote ggpmisc.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100) + 2*x +10
dados <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

formula <- y ~ x

ggplot(dados, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = T, color = "black", formula = formula) +
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq(aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label..,
                            sep = "~~~~")), 
                        formula = formula, parse = TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label..,
                            sep = "~~~~")),
                        formula = formula, parse = TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Para ficar registrada mais uma opção: a função `ggpubr::stat_regline_equation`. A sintaxe é a mesma da `ggpmisc::stat_poly_eq`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(dados, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  stat_regline_equation(aes(label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "*plain(\",\")~~")))
```

Se a fórmula não for especificada, assume-se *y ~ x*.