# Inserção de equação da reta e do R^2 em um gráfico do ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Eu gostaria de saber (1) **como obter a equação da reta** e (2) **como inserir a equação da reta e o R^2** no meu gráfico gerado pelo **ggplot**. Pesquisando aqui, encontrei dúvidas parecidas, mas por inexperiência minha no ambiente R não consegui modificar o meu script de modo que funcionasse. Nas respostas que encontrei aqui, também fiquei com a impressão que se assume que já é conhecida a equação da reta, mas eu ainda não sei como obtê-la. Segue abaixo o meu código, está funcionando, porém sem a equação da reta e o R^2 como eu precisaria.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(1358, 1464, 1425, 1174, 1296, 1011, 1083, 1206, 1037, 1150, 1092, 1069, 1259, 1225, 1269, 1034, 1221, 1048, 1016, 1129)
y <- c(113, 202, 209, 159, 205, 152, 242, 170, 198, 152, 210, 221, 168, 204, 167, 176, 179, 103, 86, 82)

dados<-data.frame(y, x)
ggplot(dados, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Desde já agradeço, toda a ajuda será bem vinda.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como colocar a equação da regressão em um gráfico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6979/como-colocar-a-equa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-da-regress%c3%a3o-em-um-gr%c3%a1fico)

Comment: Testei aqui e deu certo. Muito obrigado, respondeu à pergunta sim!