# Plot da distribuição dos graus de um grafo em R

Tags: r, plot

Tenho um grafo e quero plotar a distribuição dos graus. Exemplo:

```
> library(igraph)
> g <- make_ring(10)
> degree(g)
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
> g2 <- sample_gnp(1000, 10/1000)
> degree_distribution(g2)
 [1] 0.000 0.000 0.001 0.008 0.017 0.045 0.061 0.096 0.103 0.133 0.127 0.102 0.103 0.069 0.046 0.039 0.026 0.012 0.007
[20] 0.000 0.003 0.002
```

Quero plotar a distribuição dos graus com escala log, mais ou menos como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode pedir a escala em log direto no comando do plot:

```
g2   <- sample_gnp(1000, 10/1000)
dg2  <- degree_distribution(g2)
x  <- 1:max(degree(g2)) - 1
zeros <- (dg2 == 0) # para remover os zeros (pois log(0) é infinito)
plot(x[!zeros], dg2[!zeros], log = "xy", 
     xlab = "Log Degree", 
     ylab = "Log Frequency")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O gráfico do seu exemplo não vai ficar igual ao seu desenho pois você simulou o modelo de Erdos-Renyi. O seu desenho segue uma power law.

Para uma simulação mais parecida com o que você quer:

```
g2   <- sample_fitness_pl(10000, 30000, 2.2, 2.3)
dg2  <- degree_distribution(g2)
x  <- 1:max(degree(g2)) - 1
zeros <- dg2 == 0
plot(x[!zeros], dg2[!zeros], log = "xy", 
     xlab = "Log Degree", 
     ylab = "Log Frequency")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ótimo carlos. Mas tenho 2 dúvidas. Primeira:Como fixar o eixo Y entre 0 e 1? Ou seja, gostaria q ficasse: 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1 (já que a probabilidade varia entre 0 e 1.  Segunda: Como faço para ter a linha que acompanha o ponto (line power fit)?

Comment: Você pode ajustar os limites do eixo Y com a opção `ylim = c(1e-05, 1)`, você não pode colocar zero literalmente pois está tirando o log, e log(0) é infinito. Quanto à linha de regressão, depois de ajustar a regressão que você quer você pode colocar com `abline(modelo)` como sugerido aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6269/5010 mas lembre que essa pode não ser a melhor forma de estimar a power law.

Comment: Qual a melhor forma de estimar a power law?