# Curva não se ajusta no lines

Tags: r

Estou tentado incluir a curva predita no meu gráfico, mas ela não se ajusta. Estou usando o seguinte argumento:

```
plot(df$n.kill, df$body)
lines(df$n.kill,predict(fit,df$n.kill))
```

Dados:

```
n.kill<-c(79,4,86,9,10,49,45,260,10,8,182,16,824,2,11,112)
body<-c(160,1.5,23,40,4.5,4.5,0.8,3,1.2,60,70,0.5,35,30.5,4,47)
df<-data.frame(n.kill, body)
ca=max(df$n.kill)

eps <- .Machine$double.eps^0.5
fit <- nls(n.kill ~ a*(1 - exp(-b*body))^c, data = df, 
           start = list(a = ca, b = 0.05, c = 1), 
           algorithm = 'port', 
           control = nls.control(maxiter = 100, tol = eps))
```

Comment: Tente ao contrário, `n.kill` é a resposta, deverá estar no eixo dos y tal como o resultado de `predict`. No eixo dos x deverá estar `body`.

Comment: O ajuste da curva ainda continua com "erro", são plotadas várias linhas emaranhadas, ao invés de somente uma com a curva predita.

Comment: Veja a terceira resposta aqui, a que usa a função `curve` https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6267/como-colocar-a-linha-de-regress%c3%a3o-em-um-gr%c3%a1fico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com os dados da pergunta aqui estão duas maneiras de traçar o gráfico com a curva prevista.

## R base

O problema das linhas emaranhadas resolve-se ordenando a variável do eixo dos x e, depois, usar essa variável ordenada para calcular os valores de y.

```
b <- sort(df$body)
new <- data.frame(body = b)
with(df, plot(body, n.kill))
with(df, lines(b, predict(fit, newdata = new)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em vez de ordenar `body`, outra maneira, talvez melhor, é criar um vetor para os valores do eixo dos x com `seq`.

```
b <- seq(min(df$body), max(df$body), length.out = 500)
```

O resto do código é exatamente igual.

## Pacote `ggplot2`

Com o pacote `ggplot2`, não é necessário ajustar o modelo antes de traçar o gráfico, a `geom_smooth` faz isso desde que também se passem os argumentos usados no *fit*.

**Mas cuidado**, a `geom_smooth` só usa variáveis com os nomes `x` e `y`, as mesmas de `aes()`. É portanto necessário modificar a fórmula para usar esses nomes.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = body, y = n.kill)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'nls',
              formula = y ~ a*(1 - exp(-b*x))^c,
              se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(start = list(a = ca, b = 0.05, c = 1),
                                 algorithm = 'port',
                                 control = nls.control(maxiter = 100, tol = eps)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado novamente,  Rui.

Comment: @MiltondePaula O que fazer quando [alguém responde](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) às suas perguntas.