# Erro quando tento executar nls

Tags: r

Aparece o seguinte erro:

"Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env, ifelse(internalPars <  : 
  Obtido valor faltante ou infinito quando avaliando o modelo"

Quando eu tento executar um nls pela seguinte fórmula:

```
ca=max(df$y)
    eps <- .Machine$double.eps^0.5
    fit <- nls(y ~ a*(1 - exp(-b*x))^c, data = df, 
               start = list(a = ca, b = 0.05, c = 1), 
               algorithm = 'port', 
               control = nls.control(maxiter = 100,tol = eps))
```

Dados usados:

```
y<-c(79,86,9,10,49,45,260,10,8,182,824,2,11,112)
x<-c(1.22,2.01,2.7,3,2.5,1.49,1.46,1.5,1.31,1.95,1.58,1.62,1.9,1.42)
df<-data.frame(y, x)
```

Qual poderia ser o problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versão do R e dos pacotes `minpack.lm` e `ggplot2`.

```
R.version.string
#[1] "R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)"
packageVersion('minpack.lm')
#[1] ‘1.2.1’
packageVersion('ggplot2')
#[1] ‘3.3.0’
```

Versão do Ubuntu.

```
rui@rui:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
rui@rui:~$
```

---

Ao tentar o código da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/456535/82237) do 
Carlos Eduardo Lagosta não obtive os mesmos resultados, o código deu um aviso de não convergência em 50 iterações.

> Warning message:
>   In nls.lm(par = start, fn = FCT, jac = jac, control = control, lower = lower,  :
>     lmdif: info = -1. Number of iterations has reached `maxiter' == 50.

E, portanto, os valores dos parâmetros ajustados foram diferentes.

```
fit
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: y ~ a * (1 - exp(-b * x))^c
#   data: df
#         a          b          c 
# 6.783e+01  1.341e-06 -4.380e-02 
# residual sum-of-squares: 605975
#
#Number of iterations till stop: 50 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
#Reason stopped: Number of iterations has reached `maxiter' == 50.
```

Tentei então com valores diferentes para `maxiter` e `ptol`, que podem ser passados a `nlsLM` através de `control = nls.lm.control(.)`.

```
library(minpack.lm)
library(ggplot2)

eps <- .Machine$double.eps^0.5

fit <- nlsLM(y ~ a*(1 - exp(-b*x))^c, data = df,
             start = list(a = max(df$y), b = 0.05, c = 1),
             control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 100, ptol = eps))

summary(fit)
#
#Formula: y ~ a * (1 - exp(-b * x))^c
#
#Parameters:
#    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#a  1.297e-02  8.481e+01   0.000    1.000
#b  2.372e-05  1.715e-01   0.000    1.000
#c -9.049e-01  2.271e+00  -0.399    0.698
#
#Residual standard error: 231.9 on 11 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 93 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
#
```

Agora o gráfico mas com o pacote `ggplot` seguindo o exemplo da resposta a [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/453675/curva-n%c3%a3o-se-ajusta-no-lines).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'nlsLM',
              formula = y ~ a*(1 - exp(-b*x))^c,
              se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(start = list(a = max(df$y), b = 0.05, c = 1),
                                 algorithm = 'port',
                                 control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 100, ptol = eps)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu usei o seu exemplo, mas a curva se ajustou igual ao exemplo do Carlos Eduardo Lagosta

Comment: @MiltondePaula Pelos vistos há diferenças de resultados se as versões do R forem diferentes. Quais as suas versões do R, SO e pacote?

Comment: a versão é a 1.2.5001, mas já notei aqui que existe uma versão mais atualizada, meu SO é o Windows 10 versão 1903 e a versão do pacote "minpack.lm" é 1.2-1...

Comment: @MiltondePaula Isso não é a versão do R, é a versão do RStudio. A minha é a 1.2.5042. Para ter a versão do R corra `R.version` ou `R.version.string`.

Comment: Agora correto: "version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)", @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 2):

O `nls` é particularmente suscetível a estimativas ruins dos parâmetros (ou por valores iniciais muito distantes e/ou modelos com parametrização pouco adequada aos dados). Uma alternativa no caso de não conseguir estabelecer valores iniciais razoáveis é usar a função `minpack.lm::nlsLM`: ela transforma a fórmula em uma função e invoca LM para otimizar os valores iniciais dos parâmetros antes de chamar o NLS:

```
library(minpack.lm)

fit <- nlsLM(y ~ a*(1 - exp(-b*x))^c, data = df,
             start = list(a = max(df$y), b = 0.05, c = 1))

> summary(fit)

Formula: y ~ a * (1 - exp(-b * x))^c

Parameters:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
a 1.484e+02  5.376e+03   0.028    0.978
b 9.182e-09  1.971e-06   0.005    0.996
c 1.267e-02  2.055e+00   0.006    0.995

Residual standard error: 235.1 on 11 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 35
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```

No seu caso, seria interessante rever o modelo que está usando, já que ele é pouco descritivo para seus dados:

```
plot(df$x, df$y)
lines(df$x, predict(fit), col = "red")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usei minpack.lm versão 1.2-1, em um computador Debian Linux 10.4 64 bits rodando R 3.5.2.

Comment: Tive problemas ao correr o seu código, veja a minha resposta.

Comment: Rodei em uma sessão limpa e rodou normal. Rodando com e sem `control = nls.control(maxiter = 100, tol = eps)` cheguei nos mesmos valores. Diferença nos sistemas/versões dos pacotes, talvez?

Comment: Acrescentei esses dados à resposta. R 4.0.1, minpack.lm 1.2.1, Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: minpack.lm 1.2-1, R 3.5.2, Debian Linux 10.4

Comment: É hora de atualizar! (pelo menos o R, que é grátis :)).

Comment: Rs, uso um servidor para análise de dados que roda muitas coisas sensíveis em dados privados. A não ser que haja real necessidade de versão mais nova, me atenho às versões do repositório estável do Debian.